# What does Nginx Proxy Filter in Fail2ban really do?

Tags: nginx, iptables, mod-proxy, fail2ban, filter

**What does Nginx Proxy Filter in Fail2ban really do?**

I am currently setting up Fail2Ban for Nginx. Almost everywhere I've read, they all have included a setting for `[nginx-proxy]` proxy filter. From the examples, I can see how this filter bans the ipaddress that does things like these in the log:

```
58.218.204.110 - - [06/Mar/2011:08:04:42 -0800] "GET http://www.shopsline.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [06/Mar/2011:11:01:33 -0800] "GET http://www.foodnese.com/indux.php HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [06/Mar/2011:16:00:18 -0800] "GET http://98.126.64.106/judge123.php HTTP/1.1" 403 502 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.204.110 - - [06/Mar/2011:16:19:08 -0800] "GET http://98.126.64.106/judge123.php HTTP/1.1" 403 502 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [06/Mar/2011:18:30:13 -0800] "GET http://www.travelimgusa.com/ip.php HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [06/Mar/2011:23:27:23 -0800] "GET http://www.seektwo.com/proxy-1.php HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.204.110 - - [07/Mar/2011:00:36:45 -0800] "GET http://www.eduju.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [07/Mar/2011:04:27:13 -0800] "GET http://www.eduju.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [07/Mar/2011:09:24:13 -0800] "GET http://98.126.64.106/judge123.php HTTP/1.1" 403 502 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [07/Mar/2011:14:25:03 -0800] "GET http://www.foodnese.com/indux.php HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [07/Mar/2011:16:54:09 -0800] "GET http://www.foodnese.com/indux.php HTTP/1.1" 404 498 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [07/Mar/2011:19:21:51 -0800] "GET http://www.racross.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 503 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [08/Mar/2011:05:19:50 -0800] "GET http://piceducation.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 301 605 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [08/Mar/2011:15:15:22 -0800] "GET http://www.piggmail.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [08/Mar/2011:17:43:58 -0800] "GET http://www.cjpjp.com/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
58.218.199.147 - - [08/Mar/2011:20:14:15 -0800] "GET http://98.126.64.106/judge123.php HTTP/1.1" 403 502 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
```

But what I dont understand is, what are these guys really trying to do? Are these ip addresses trying to use my server to fetch another site for them? How does these proxy attacks work? I cant seem to find much info on how my server can be used as proxy and why I need the proxy filter for.